# Letter Occurrences and Frequency python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, frequency

I need to create a list of letter occurrences from a list of words.

my list of words is    ['song', 'boom', 'pow']

I want to count the letter occurrences in each word and then put them in a list in alphabetical order. If there isn't a letter in my word list that matches each letter in the alphabet, I still want it to print a 0 in the list.

Instead of typing out a string of 26 characters in the alphabet, I am using `string.ascii_lowercase`

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

I then I need to find out the letter occurrences in each word and which word[s] the letter is shown in.

Then output should look like:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
'o' in 'song', 'boom', 'pow'
etc.
```

Comment: @Vyktor this goes along with my other question you recently answered, if you could help?

Answer (score 4):

The first part can be done like so:

```
In [12]: seq = ['song', 'boom', 'pow']

In [13]: c = collections.Counter(''.join(seq))

In [14]: [c.get(l, 0) for l in string.ascii_lowercase]
Out[14]: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

As to the second part, here is a hint:

```
In [23]: [w for w in seq if 'o' in w]
Out[23]: ['song', 'boom', 'pow']
```

Comment: Why not just `collections.Counter(''.join(seq))`, which is a lot shorter, simpler conceptually, and probably even faster?

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your `for l in string.ascii_lowercase` expression. Can you write this a different way without putting the for loop inside there? @NPE

Comment: @perkypanda: All the loop does is assign each letter of `string.ascii_lowercase` to `l` in turn. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: okay, thanks! and if I wanted to make a calculation with the occurrence, say turn it into a frequency (by means of calling another function to calculate) how would I go about appending that in place of the part where you have `c.get(l,0)` ? could I do `c.get(function(),0)` or would that notation not work in alphabetical order then? @NPE

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from string import ascii_lowercase
l = ['song', 'boom', 'pow']
od = OrderedDict(((k,0) for k in ascii_lowercase)) # create dict from alph with initial val of 0
for word in l:
    for let in word: 
        o[let] += 1 # increase value by 1 for each letter in the words
print(od.values()) # ordereddict keeps order so just print values
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]


for k in od:
    for word in l:
        if k in word:
            print(k,word)
('b', 'boom')
('g', 'song')
('m', 'boom')
('n', 'song')
('o', 'song')
('o', 'boom')
('o', 'pow')
('p', 'pow')
('s', 'song')
('w', 'pow')
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Another way that seems natural to me:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> words= ['song', 'boom', 'pow']
>>> s=''.join(words)
>>> [s.count(c) for c in ascii_lowercase]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

For the second part, just use a nested loop:

```
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    li=[]
    for word in words:
        if c in word:
            li.append(word)
    if li:
        print '{} in {}'.format(c, ', '.join(li))
```

Prints:

```
b in boom
g in song
m in boom
n in song
o in song, boom, pow
p in pow
s in song
w in pow
```